# What does the first <U> in this statement mean?

Tags: java, generics, predicate

```
public static <U> Predicate<U> isEqualsTo(U u) {
    return s -> s.equals(u);
    /*Predicate<U>  return type
    U u is the parameter
    s-> s.equals(u) is the lambda expression */
}
```

What does the first `<U>` before `Predicate<U>` mean ?

Comment: You must declare a type parameter before you can use it. The first `<U>` declares it, the second in `Predicate<U>` and the parameter type `U` use it. That’s different to type declarations like `class MyClass<T>` which declares and uses `T` at the same time. Besides that, in this specific case, using `U` as parameter type is nonsensical. It would work with `Object` as well, as done in Java 8’s [`Predicate.isEqual(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#isEqual-java.lang.Object-)…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the generic type of the method. For example, something less complex:

```
public static <U> void doSomething(U u) {
    System.out.println(u);
}
```

You can parametrize any function, that you want in Java, just like you'd do with Classes. And it doesn't just work for static methods, but instance methods as well. You could call the function like this:

```
<String>doSomething("hello");
<Integer>doSomething(42);
```

The great thing is, that Type Inference works really well in Java when using generic methods, so you could call the above function like this:

```
doSomething("hello,world");
doSomething(42);
```

without telling the compiler what type you're using.

Check out the documentation [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

Comment: What do we mean mean by generic type of the method ? Generic return type, generic parameter is understood, but what does generic type of method mean ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: It means you can specify a generic return type or parameter as you wish. You can call my method above with any Type parameter you wish and the arguement of the function will change according to the type parameter. You can also have multiple type parameters for multiple types of arguments. :)

Answer (score 2):

The first `<U>` declares the generic type `U` of your method. It is a placeholder that replaces a static type definition.

With this generic function, you can now use any type of input, as the type of your input parameter `u` is `U`, our generic type placeholder.

The output of this generic function is defined as another generic object, an instance of `Predicate<>`, but parametrized with the same generic type `U` that we used as input type.

```
//           | generic type(s) of this method
//           |
//           |   | type of return value  | type of parameter   
//           \___\____________           \_
public static <U> Predicate<U> isEqualsTo(U u) {
    return s -> s.equals(u);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us say you have

```
public abstract class Predicate<T> 
{

    public static <U> Predicate<U> isEqualsTo(U u) {
        return null;
    }
    public static void isNotEqualsTo(Object u) {

    }
}
```

Then return type must be same what you are passing.

```
public class Temp 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Predicate<String> str=Predicate.isEqualsTo(new String("ewrqe"));
        Predicate<Integer> integer=Predicate.isEqualsTo(new Integer(200));

        Predicate.isNotEqualsTo(new String("ewrqe"));
        Predicate.isNotEqualsTo(new Integer(200));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that the method is generic so can return any specified type as specified when invoked.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html